How do I do a trailing X day rolling group by sum in Snowflake?
I did some googling and research and got this as allowing me to do a group by trailing 60 row sum.
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    EVENT_DATE
    , CUSTOMERID
    , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfViews
  FROM TABLE
  AND EVENT_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -360, GETDATE())
  GROUP BY EVENT_DATE, CUSTOMERID
)

SELECT
  EVENT_DATE
  , CUSTOMERID
  , SUM(NumberOfViews) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMERID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ASC ROWS BETWEEN 60 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS NumberOfViews60D
FROM CTE
ORDER BY
    CUSTOMERID, EVENT_DATE;

Which works fine! However, I want the rolling 60 day sum, not 60 row sum.  I got this as an answer but it doesn't work.  What should I do?
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    EVENT_DATE
    , CUSTOMERID
    , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfViews
  FROM TABLE
  AND EVENT_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -360, GETDATE())
  GROUP BY EVENT_DATE, CUSTOMERID
)

SELECT
  EVENT_DATE
  , CUSTOMERID
  , SUM(NumberOfViews) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMERID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ASC RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '60 DAY' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS NumberOfViews60D
FROM CTE
ORDER BY
    CUSTOMERID, EVENT_DATE;

I get the error: "Invalid window frame"

Snowflake window frames are row-based, not date value based.  However, if your event_date is truly at the date level, then you could leverage a date dimension table, do a left join, and then you'll have a row for every date for every customerid, which will make the preceding 60 rows the same as the preceding 60 days.

You can solve this with a self join (in a correlated sub-query here):
with data as (
    select '2020-01-01'::date date, 1 value
    union all select '2020-01-15', 2
    union all select '2020-01-20', 1
    union all select '2020-01-25', 20
    union all select '2020-02-15', 1
    union all select '2020-03-15', 2
    union all select '2020-04-15', 1
    union all select '2020-05-15', 2
)

select a.date
    , a.value
    , (
        select sum(b.value)
        from data b
        where b.date between dateadd(day, -59, a.date) and a.date
    ) rolling_sum_60_days
from data a


If you also need the customer ids:
with data as (
    select '2020-01-01'::date date, 1 value, 'a' id
    union all select '2020-01-15', 2, 'b'
    union all select '2020-01-20', 1, 'a'
    union all select '2020-01-25', 20, 'b'
    union all select '2020-02-15', 1, 'a'
    union all select '2020-03-15', 2, 'b'
    union all select '2020-04-15', 1, 'a'
    union all select '2020-05-15', 2, 'b'
)

select a.id
    , a.date
    , a.value
    , (
        select sum(b.value)
        from data b
        where b.date between dateadd(day, -59, a.date) and a.date
        and a.id=b.id
    ) rolling_sum_60_days
from data a
group by all
order by a.id, a.date;



RANGE Clause is now available in Snowflake Window Functions. You can use the following query:
Input data



DATE_VIEWED
VIEWS
CUSTOMER_ID




2020-01-01
1
a


2020-01-15
2
b


2020-01-20
1
a


2020-01-25
20
b


2020-02-15
1
a


2020-03-15
2
b


2020-04-15
1
a


2020-05-15
2
b



SQL Query
select 
  *
  , sum(views) over (partition by customer_id
order by date_viewed 
range between interval '59 day' preceding and current row) rolling_sum_of_views_last_60_days
from page_views
; 

Query Output



DATE_VIEWED
VIEWS
CUSTOMER_ID
ROLLING_SUM_OF_VIEWS_LAST_60_DAYS




2020-01-01
1
a
1


2020-01-20
1
a
2


2020-02-15
1
a
3


2020-04-15
1
a
1


2020-01-15
2
b
2


2020-01-25
20
b
22


2020-03-15
2
b
22


2020-05-15
2
b
2



More info here:
https://qosf.com/RANGE-clause-in-window-functions-practical-examples.html
